# Xamarin Forms ListView ItemsSource issue

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

I have a ListView and its ItemsSource.

```
ListView IList = new ListView();
IList.ItemsSource = _routine_names;
```

In order to customize the Data Template for each item I'm doing:

```
IList.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(()=>
        {
            Label Routine_Name = new Label(); // should be_routine_names
            return new ViewCell
            {
                View = new StackLayout{
                    Children = {Routine_Name}
                }
            };
        });
```

When I run this my ListView is displayed and the list items are indeed there (they have onclick handlers that work) but there is no text, which should be whatever is in _routine_names.

My question how do I get the Label in the DataTemplate to be items in _routine_names?

The reason I'm adding a DataTemplate is so I can add swipe to delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the built in [TextCell](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TextCell/) for what you're trying to do. It has a bindable TextProperty and an optional DetailProperty if you want a smaller text line below the main one.

```
IList.ItempTemplate = new DataTemplate(()=> 
{
    var textCell = new TextCell();
    textCell.ContextActions.Add(yourAction);
    textCell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "."); 
    return textCell; 
}

IList.ItemsSource = _routine_names;
```

`yourAction` is of type MenuItem as seen [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#C)

Also, please notice that `IList` is a name of a class in System.Collection namespace so I'd use something else there.

Comment: What is "Routine_Name" in the second parameter supposed to be? My _routine_names is simply an ObservableCollection of strings.

Comment: @justin If it's just ObservableCollection<string>, you can set the binding to `.` which will point to each string in the collection. I updated my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: @justing Did you get it to work with the latest change?

Comment: @justin Great to hear!